# Site is slow to complete php file

Tags: php, html, http, iis

I have a website running on an internal server at work. For some reason, pages are taking about five seconds to load and I can't figure out why.
Looking at the network performance in Firefox, it is always bg.gif that is last to load and there's a huge gap between it loading and the rest of the page.
What could be causing this delay and how do I fix it?

**Updated**
I was mis-reading the Network performance chart and thought the long bar at the top for the page file encompassed all the elements below. Turns out it is this that is taking so long to load.
It is a php file (index.php) which builds the html, so my first thought was that the php processing on the sever was causing the delay. However, the page contents appear immediately (less than 500ms) and there's no noticable change when the page is 'fully loaded'.
Additionally, if I remove all the code and load an empty file, it still takes around 5 seconds.
Is it possible the php processing is having trouble closing the file for some reason?

[image: Network performance]

Comment: Make the gif smaller? It would make sense that large image file that is used as a background would take a little while to load

Comment: mituw16 - the file is tiny, 64 bytes

Comment: According to your network graph, bg.gif loaded in 14 ms and seems to have been waiting ~5 seconds on `index.php`...

Comment: mellamokb - Yes, you're right. I was mis-reading the graph and thought that was the overall load time. I've updated my original question accordingly.

Comment: If you get the HTTP headers wrong, the browser may stall waiting for more content until it times out. This can happen if you get send the wrong `Content-Length` for compressed content, or getting the byte count or line endings wrong for `chunked` responses, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to have been a PHP MySQL driver issue, specific to the (very outdated) versions on my server. A driver update has fixed the issue.